# ¿Como confirmo que un id de una URL sea la misma que se ha enviado en un formulario con un Form Request?

Tags: php, laravel

me encuentro desarrollando un sistema para crear reservaciones en restaurantes. Actualmente quiero hacer una autorización para poder hacer una reservación segura, es decir, que seleccionado un restaurante la reservación se haga en este mismo.
El problema que tengo es que no sé cómo podría hacer una corroboración de datos para confirmar que el id del restaurante que se envía por el formulario coincida con el que se encuentra en la URL (el id real del restaurante). Les muestro mi código.

**URL**

```
http://restaurante.test/restaurant/west-inc/reservation/create
```

El id de este restaurante es el 100, solo que estoy mostrando el slug en lugar de su id correspondiente.
Al hacer un envío de datos para corroborar que sí se están enviando los datos, obtengo lo siguiente (un ejemplo):

```
{
  "_token": "LQu9tkue3QAYHDDdPpDnu4BpBfYNNQrByz6toPsu",

  "restaurant_id": "100",

  "name": "dsadsadsadas",

  "persons": "1",

  "date": "2021-07-29",

  "email": "luis@gmail.com"
}
```

Esto me hace entender que sí se están enviando los datos. Al hacer datos de prueba no estoy realizando el método create().
Ya agregué el Request correspondiente al controlador. La parte para mostrar los datos de prueba que estoy utilizando son:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->all();
   return $request;
}
```

**StoreReservationRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Models\Restaurant;

class StoreReservationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
                //Aquí es donde no sé cómo hacer la comparación
       if () { //Autorizar si el id de la categoría de la url coincide con la del campo hidden
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Bueno, creo que eso es todo... espero su ayuda y gracia de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente te es tan importante garantizar que el restaurante el cual se envía en la URL coincida con el id del hidden, lo cual debe de serlo, porque además permíteme comentarte que cualquiera puede modificar los datos a su gusto incluso en el Hidden, lo cual te puede traer el problema de que un supuesto hacker en un futuro haga que el pedido de un restaurante acabe en otro...

Si quieres pasar datos en el hidden, como mínimo debes encriptarlos para garantizar la integridad de los mismos, esto como mínimo.

Ejemplo:

Encriptas el ID, pones su valor encriptado en el hidden, y en el código encargado de recibir el hidden lo desencriptas, de esta forma garantizado su integridad.

**Pero este método es en realidad una chapuza**, y lo que deberías hacer es guardar los pedidos en una base de datos, y solo confiar los datos que haya en esa base de datos y no un input que el cliente puede modificar a su gusto.

Un saludo,

Comment: Precisamente estoy guardando los datos en una bbdd, por eso me interesa hacer la comparación entre los datos existentes y los datos enviados... Verás, Todos los restaurantes que se muestran son obtenidos de mi bbdd, entonces, al yo hacer clic en un botón llamado "reservar" me lleva directamente a una subcarpeta con el id del restaurante que seleccioné.... No sé si me explique... El campo hidden contiene el campo "id" de mi tabla "restaurantes" de la bbdd. Por eso mismo quiero hacer la comparación de que coincida el URL del restaurante en cuestión con el del hidden (para evitar que lo cambien).

Comment: Entonces reformula la pregunta ya que no queda lo suficientemente claro que tienes y que quieres. Yo antes de encriptar soy partidario de tokenizar, pero esto depende de que tengas y que quieras.(Con absoluta precisión)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación, he resuelto el problema. Responderé a esta pregunta con la respuesta que hice. Soy nuevo en este framework pero tengo un poco de experiencia con situaciones así. Aún así, muchas gracias por tus comentarios, saludos! :D

Answer (score 0):

he resuelto este problema de la siguiente manera:
Para evitar que algún usuario malicioso cambie cosas de el front (como el input tipo hidden con el id del restaurante) opté por enviar el ID a través del servidor... Esto lo hice de la siguiente manera:

En el método store agregué la clase que utilizo para los restaurantes, para de esta manera recuperar el ID que estoy obteniendo en la URL sin necesidad de mandar este mismo a la vista con la posibilidad de que puedan cambiarlo.

Ya teniendo esta clase, en el método create especifico los campos a ingresas a la bbdd y su contenido. Todos estos a través del parámetro **$request**, a excepción del campo **restaurant_id**, el cuál es traído a través del parámetro **$restaurant** en el cuál se están guardando los datos del restaurante en el que se desee hacer la reservación.

```
public function store(Request $request,Restaurant $restaurant)
{
    $reservation = Reservation::create([
        'restaurant_id' => $restaurant['id'],
        'client_name' => $request['client_name'],
        'persons' => $request['persons'],
        'date' => $request['date'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
    ]);
    return $reservation;
}
```

También modifiqué mi tabla de migración correspondiente a esta misma, agregándole el método *nullable* a dos campos, quedando de esta manera:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('persons')->nullable();

        $table->date('date')->nullable();

        $table->string('client_name');
        $table->string('email');
        
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('restaurant_id');

        $table->foreign('restaurant_id')->references('id')->on('restaurants')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

y por último, a mi modelo le agregué la propiedad *guarded* para estar seguro contra ataques de asignación masiva.

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','updated_at'];

        //Relación uno a muchos inversa
        public function restaurant()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Restaurant::class);
        }
}
```

Eso fue todo lo que hice. No lo probé luego por unos imprevistos que surgieron, pero ahora que me desocupé, lo he probado y ha funcionado bien.
Espero esta solución le pueda servir a alguien más, saludos!